# Android: Adding View inflated from XML Layout to Viewgroup which has not defined any width yet

Tags: android, xml, layout, layout-inflater, viewgroup

I have a layout problem with my custom viewgroup class.

I call init() in the constructor. In my init() function I inflate the viewgroups layout from an xml file, which contains a LinearLayout to which I add several other views.

I am using spacer (View layout_width="0" and layout_weight="1") to distribute the items equaly.

The problem lies here: the layout still has not defined any width when i add the children. So the spacer all have the size 0, and wont actually place the "line_dot" items equally. How can i somehow update their size?

```
public class SliderSwitch extends FrameLayout {

...
    public SliderSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_switch,this);


        sliderLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliderLayout);
        labelLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.labelLayout);


        // add one spacer
        View spacer = (View) inflate(context,R.layout.spacer, null);
        sliderLayout.addView(spacer);

        // setup the view depending on how many elements there are
        for (int i=1;i<numberOfElements-1;i++) {

            ImageView lineDot = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_switch_line_dot, null);
            sliderLayout.addView(lineDot);

            View spacer = (View) inflate(context,R.layout.spacer, null);
            sliderLayout.addView(spacer);
        }

    }
... 
}
```

this is the xml file for the spacer:

```
<View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

and this is the one for my viewgroup layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/left_bg" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliderLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/middle_bg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

               <!-- <include layout="@layout/spacer"/> -->

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/right_bg" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sliderKnob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/knob" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution now. You have to set the LayoutParams in the code again (even if they are already defined in the xml file), then everything is neatly spaced, how its supposed to. seems to be a bug. But this solution works:

```
    // add one spacer
    View spacer = (View) inflate(context,R.layout.spacer, null);
    spacer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0F));
    sliderLayout.addView(spacer);

    // setup the view depending on how many elements there are

    for (int i=1;i<numberOfElements-1;i++) {

        ImageView lineDot = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_switch_line_dot, null);

        sliderLayout.addView(lineDot);

        spacer = (View) inflate(context,R.layout.spacer, null);
        spacer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(1,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0F));
        sliderLayout.addView(spacer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call init() on [onSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) callback. Remember to set and keep a flag in order to avoid calling it twice, since this callback may run more than once.

Comment: good idea. I tried it. but i guess the problem lies somewhere else since i am still not able to get the spacer work correctly. :(

Comment: its strange, when i add the spacers directly in the layout file by using <include ... > everything looks fine. but if i add them in code, they dont work.

Comment: You're setting spacer height to zero, so the view won't be drawn. The weight attribute only afects width in this case, since you're using horizontal orientation. It doesn't matter if your view gets horizontally streched if height = 0.

Comment: putting the height of the spacer to match_parent didnt work either